# Overlay text from a variable at the bottom of every image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, text, overlay

I'm hoping to overlay text from a variable at the bottom of every image using jquery preferably, or javascript.

Here's the project I'm working on - http://codepen.io/chrismcintosh/pen/ejzut.

This is the first javascript I've ever produced so don't be too hard on me.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What variable are you trying to overlay on top of the image?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: it's a bit hard without a little more context. I can see your codpen but what in the codpen represents the text you want to overlay on the picture?

Comment: I'm hoping to overlay the event title located in the variable "event"

Comment: When do you expect the JS to populate the event name?  Currently your only JS is onClick and that means it won't populate until someone clicks it.

Comment: @ametren The event name would need to populate on page load.

Comment: 1) using id like a "Run Or Dye" it's not valid(spaces)
2) using id like a "3rd Friday"  also not valid(id must NOT start from number)
where do you wnat to text appear? in modal window, or on image in static? can't understand what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little light on the details but hopefully this helps.  First, you need to add an element that will hold the data to your HTML.  You can do this via JS instead of via HTML if you want, but here goes:

```
<img src="http://greatworkperks.com/sites/default/files/perks/RunorDye2.jpg" 
class="tile" id="Run Or Dye" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
onclick="myFunction(this.id)">
<!-- Below is the new div -->
<div id="RunOrDye_Overlay" class="overlay">Run or Dye</div>
```

Next, add the corresponding CSS style.  Here is one that might work:

```
DIV.overlay{
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  top: 110px;
  left: -290px;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
}
```

At this point your overlay exists.  I'm not sure if you need your JS to actually do anything at this point -- you could set up your JS to toggle this div when the user hovers over the image or something like that.

Does this help?

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but I think I know what you're trying to do and I would change the entire approach.  Probably you want to set up an array with an object for each of your images when the page loads, rather than creating those variables inside your switch statement on click

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for, but I believe it solves my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the overlays into your html, you can use jQuery's [`.wrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function to wrap each tile, and then append a text element to each wrapper.

```
// wrap each tile in a span
$('.tile').wrap('<span class="tile-wrapper"></span>')

// append the text to each wrapper
$('.tile-wrapper').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.append('<div class="image-text">' + $this.find('img').attr('id') + '</div>');
});
```

If you make each wrapper element `position: relative` and each text overlay `position: absolute` the overlays will automatically be positioned in the middle of each tile. Then you can adjust the overlay's `bottom` property to put them at the bottom of the tile.

Here's the updated **[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zCHaD)**